# docker executor vs docker dind image

Tags: gitlab-ci

I am a newbie in gitlabci. I want to understand why do we need docker dind image in order to build a docker image in GitLab CI jobs. Why can't we use the docker executor and run docker commands under scripts?

When we register docker executor gitlab runner, we choose one image..
Again inside gitlabci, we choose an image under `image:` or `services:` fields. So does that mean this GitLab CI job container runs inside the docker executor container?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> why do we need docker dind image in order to build a docker image in GitLab CI jobs. Why can't we use the docker executor and run docker commands under scripts?

This partly depends on how you have configured your GitLab runner.

### Why `docker` doesn't work inside containers

When you invoke `docker` commands, they are really talking to a docker *daemon* which is needed to perform builds and carry out other docker commands. Typically, jobs running under the docker executor do not have access to any docker daemon by default. It's the same kind of problem you would face if you tried to run `docker` inside of a docker container you started locally.

Even if I can run `docker` successfully on my host:

```sh
$ docker run --rm docker /bin/sh -c 'hello from container $HOSTNAME'
hello from container 2b51479b11b1
```

I cannot run `docker` inside the container

```sh
$ docker run --rm docker /bin/sh -c 'docker info'
errors pretty printing info
Client:
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false

Server:
ERROR: error during connect: Get "http://docker:2375/v1.24/info": dial tcp: lookup docker on 192.168.65.5:53: no such host
```

The same error would happen trying to run any other significant docker command like `build`, `run`, etc.

An exception to this would be if you configured your GitLab runner to run containers in privileged mode and mount `/var/run/docker.sock` to all your jobs (this would not be advisable) in which case all your jobs could talk directly to the docker daemon on the host. Another exception might be if you use the `shell` executor instead and you have `docker` installed on the host where the runner is running.

### How the dind service fixes this

The `docker:dind` service is a daemon that is created *just* for your job. This is incredibly important because it can prevent concurrent jobs from stepping on one another or being able to escalate access where they might not otherwise have it.

When the build starts, the GitLab runner will create two containers: your job container and the `docker:dind` container; they are linked together. When your job invokes `docker` commands, your job connects to the `docker:dind` container, which then carries out the requested commands.

Any containers created by your job (say, by invoking `docker run` or `docker build` as part of your job) are managed by the daemon running on the `docker:dind` container, not the host daemon. If you run `docker ps` inside the job, you'll notice that none of the containers run on the *host* daemon are listed, despite the fact that if you ran `docker ps` on the host, you would see the job container, the dind container, and any other running containers.

---

To clarify your other questions:

> When we register docker executor gitlab runner, we choose one image

The image specified in your runner configuration is simply the *default* docker image to be used if a job doesn't declare any `image:` key. It does not affect how the runner runs in any way.

> inside gitlabci, we choose an image under image: or services: fields

When the docker executor runs your job, it uses `docker run` to do so. The `image:` key determines which image is used to run your job. Similarly, `services:` define the image used for service containers -- service containers are *siblings* to the job container and are connected with *links*.

> So does that mean this GitLab CI job container runs inside the docker executor container?

No. I'd also like to clear up: the runner/executor doesn't run in a container, necessarily. Runners might be installed as a Windows service, or simply even a process running directly on a system. You *can* use runners that *happen* to be inside containers, but it doesn't materially affect how jobs are run.

In any case, the containers where your job run are generally always going to be run directly by the host docker daemon.

Comment: i'm a bit confused. can the ci be configured in a way, that runners are directly run on the host, not in any container, then if the job don't specify an image, then the docker build command don't need `dind`, right? i think in most cases runners are suggested to run in docker, for sake of isolation, etc? i'm a daily user, but never been a gitlab ci admin.

Comment: @LeiYang If a _docker_ executor runs a job, the job will always run in a container. If you want a job to run directly on the host, you should use the [_shell_ executor](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/shell.html) type.

Comment: *If a docker/bash executor runs a job* -- is it decided by the gitlab ci admin configs, or can be specified by the `gitlab ci yml`?

Comment: @LeiYang the runner admin decides entirely. The executor type cannot be changed by project users. The only control projects have over this is by either (1) specifying `tags:` in the job, (but this relies on there being a registered runner with the specified tag in advance), and/or (2) registering project-locked runners dedicated to the project (and disabling shared runners if using untagged jobs).

Comment: Thankyou very much @sytech . I got my queries clarified..